# Error code 404 or 405, for GET and PUT methods

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-web-api

Good day I have created a simple Web API for my app.

I was able to successfully make a POST method without conflict, and also GET without parameters(https://www.something.com/api/something/) works too, but when I insert parameter for my GET (https://www.something.com/api/something/1) it gives me a 404 on POSTMAN. When I try PUT Method, and I don't put a parameter, it gives me a 405. And 404 when I put a parameter. Below is my code.

I'm using MongoDB for my database.
database has _id, and category as Partition key.
_id also works as id(Property name JSON)

**Controller**

```
// To get a specific record
[HttpGet("{id:length(24)}")]
public ActionResult< SomeModel > Get(string id)
{
   var some = _someThing.Get(id);

   if (some == null)
   {
      return NotFound();
   }

   return some;
}

// For Updating a record
[HttpPut("{id:length(24)}")]
public IActionResult Update(string id, SomeModel pModel)
{
    var something = _someModel.Get(id);

    if (something == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    _someModel.Update(id, pModel);

    return NoContent();
}
```

**Services**

```
// For Finding a specific record
public SomeModel Get(string id) =>
_scores.Find< SomeModel >(scores => scores.id == id).FirstOrDefault();

// For Updating record
public void Update(string id, SomeModel newScore) =>
_scores.ReplaceOne(scores => scores.id == id, newScore);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-constraints) section about route constraints:

> Length: Matches a string with the specified length or within a specified range of lengths.

It looks to me like your controller is expecting an ID of 24 characters long.
Try changing it to this:

```
[HttpGet("{id:length(1,24)}")]
```

Or using `minlength` or `maxlength` instead.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. Everyone starts somewhere! :D